Summation of binomial coefficients with alternating signs
For a fixed $\alpha > 1$ and integer $n$, I want to provide some bounds or scaling results for the following summations
$$S_1(n,\alpha) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k + 1} k / (\alpha k + \alpha - 1)$$
$$S_2(n, \alpha) = \sum_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{k + 1} k^2 / (\alpha k + 2\alpha - 1)$$
I numerically computed these summations for different values of $n$ and observed that $S_1(n, \alpha)$ seems to decrease as a function of $n$ and $S_2(n, \alpha)$ while increases is always non-positive. Can this be made formal or is there a counterexample in terms of $n$ where my conjecture fails? Can we show that two summations are bounded and do not grow with $n$?
I appreciate any insights or references that could guide further investigation into these summations.

It's not hard to obtain explicit formulas:
$$S_1(n,\alpha) = \alpha^{-1}\binom{n+1-\frac1{\alpha}}n^{-1}$$
and
$$S_2(n,\alpha) = (1-2\alpha)\alpha^{-2}\binom{n+2-\frac1{\alpha}}n^{-1}.$$

Hi, thanks a lot. Could you please provide me with a sketch of how you obtained these expressions?

Note that $\frac1{\alpha k + \alpha - 1} = \frac1{\alpha} \int_0^1 t^{k-\frac1{\alpha}},dt$, which allows to perform summation under the integral and leads to an expression in terms of beta function.
